# Enhanced-dpy discord bot runs fine locally but errors in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

So my bot works fine when i run locally as you see below, But

[image: Script when run locally]

When i run it on heroku,this happens.

[image][Complete Heroku Log](https://pastebin.com/na0CKmDH)

[Complete admin.py](https://pastebin.com/g8FzqdEj) (which is apparently causing the error from what i could figure out from the log.

```
import discord
from discord import member
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands.cog import Cog
from discord_slash import cog_ext, SlashContext
from discord_slash.utils.manage_components import create_select, create_select_option, create_actionrow


__GID__ = [123332423423424] 
#(I'm lazy to edit in pastebin)


class Admin(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Admin up!")

    @cog_ext.cog_slash(name="ban", description="Ban a user from this server.", guild_ids=__GID__)
    async def ban(self, ctx, user: discord.User, *,reason=None):
        banned = discord.Embed(
            title = "User Banned",
            description = f"{user.name}#{user.discriminator} was banned by {ctx.author.mention}"
        )
        banned.add_field(name="Reason", value=f"{reason}")
        banned.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
        await user.ban(reason = reason)
```

Comment: Hello, are you using the same version's of **python** and `discord.py`?

Comment: I figured it out, apparently i was using discord.py in heroku instead of enhanced-dpy, there was an error which i fixed later.